# moving modx to new server - clear cache

Tags: caching, modx

I moved website to new server, domain stay the same, files structure stay the same, but path to public_html has beed changed. Database has been also moved.

I tried to clean cache, but i dont think I made it. This is error i get:

```
Could not find action file at: /home/account_name/domains/domain.co.uk/public_html/manager/controllers/default/welcome.php
```

`account_name` is different now.

I havent access to the old server, so I cant login and clear cache. I tried to do it using [php script](http://www.dangibbs.co.uk/journal/clear-modx-revolution-cache-from-php-script) I found, but it didnt help.

[Moving to new server documentation](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Moving+Your+Site+to+a+New+Server) - there is `welcome.php` error and how to fix it, but since I haven't access to website from old server, I can't do it.

Also I can't login and clear cache in admin panel, because this message in when i wan get access to it.

I also change in db, in `modx_workspaces`->`path` from `{core_path}` to `home/account_name/domains/domain.co.uk/publis_html/core`, but didn't help.

How can i clear cache or if it's not the case, what should I do to make it work?

**Update**

I have change location in settings:
config.core.php
connectors/config.core.php
core/config/config.inc.php
manager/config.core.php

In .htaccess I couldn't find path to website, I didn't change anything.

I remove all content from core/cache/, except one file (.gitignore), and if I go to domain.co.uk/manager/ it's blank page, no content at all. And still can't log in.

Comment: unless you have used an advanced install, change all the config.core.php back.  Did you re-run the setup?

Comment: can you see error.log in apache for more information?

Comment: This is a path problem in your config file. There are 7 or so lines that define paths and need to be changed to represent the path on your new server.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the cache on the new server manually VIA FTP or from a shell.

Change that modx_workspaces thing back

did you change all your settings in core/config/config.inc.php ?? if not do so, that is where you will set most of your paths & database credentials.

you have a backup? good!

Now upgrade to the same version of modx, that should fix all your path issues. [make sure you are not logged into the manager while trying to upgrade]

Answer (score 0):

When moving the site to the new server rather watch two things:

1. the right paths into this files

   ```
   /config.core.php
   /core/config/config.inc.php
   /connectors/config.core.php
   /manager/config.core.php
   ```
2. the folder `/core/cache/` is empty. They can be cleaned simply by removing the contents via ftp.

and correct the value in the database back to {core_path}

Comment: Unless you have moved your /manager or /core directories from their default locations you do not have to do anything with either core.config.php.

Comment: Yes, this applies more for advanced build, but if there are incorrect paths the site will not work.